# Step over Node in VB.net XML parsing

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm trying to use the XML parsing capabilities of VB.net

Here is some XML returned from Google's traffic directions API.

[image]

My VB.net code to get the Total distance value is

```
returnedDistanceMeters = returnedXML...<route>...<leg>...<distance>...<value>.Value
```

But it is "short cutting" to the value in the first "step" node and giving me 88 where I want 193108.  How do I avoid it jumping to the first node called "distance" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a better way. But every time I have to work with xml on .net I prefer to use xsd.exe to create a class.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

After adding the .vb file to your project, you can initialize the class from a xml file using this function:

```
Private Function getTraficFromFile(ByVal path As String) As trafic
    Dim stream As New IO.StreamReader(path)
    Dim ser As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(trafic))
    Dim mytrafic As New trafic
    mytrafic = CType(ser.Deserialize(stream), trafic)
    stream.Close()

    Return mytrafic
End Function
```

You can access the xml values like normal properties, in your case something like:

```
Dim mytraffic as trafic = getTraficFromFile(path)
MsgBox(mytraffic.route.leg.step(19).distance)
```

Comment: That is cool, and a good idea I try that.  The problem is the step(19) part is variable.  It needs to ignore all the step nodes and take the Value from the Distance.

Comment: @bendecko I didn't realize that the distance is outside of a "step". You can access it as an usual property of a class: MsgBox(mytraffic.route.leg.distance)