# C# - Get value from a specific tag in XML document

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an xml document which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cbn:PaidOrderNotification xmlns:cbn="http://xml.test.com/3.12.0.0/test.xsd">
    <cbn:NotificationDate>2016-08-01T07:28:46.679414Z</cbn:NotificationDate>
    <cbn:Purchase cbt:Id="95368158" xmlns:cbt="http://xml.test.com/3.12.0.0/testTypes.xsd">
        <cbt:Status>Test Order</cbt:Status>
        <cbt:Items>
            <cbt:Item cbt:RunningNo="1">
                <cbt:ProductId>178732</cbt:ProductId>
                <cbt:Payment cbt:SubscriptionId="S18767146">
                    <cbt:CancelUrl>https://store.test.com/</cbt:CancelUrl>
                    <cbt:ChangeUrl>https://test.com/</cbt:ChangeUrl>
                </cbt:Payment>
            </cbt:Item>
        </cbt:Items>
        <cbt:ExtraParameters />
    </cbn:Purchase>
</cbn:PaidOrderNotification>
```

Using C#, I want to get the value inside `<cbt:CancelUrl>` tag. How can I do that?

Comment: When I have to work with XML, I prefer to create a class with xsd. Check my answer on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243018/step-over-node-in-vb-net-xml-parsing/23243339#23243339

Comment: use `http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/` to get the strongly typed C# object for the provided `xml`.Then just deserialize it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First read the `xml` document like:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(_xml);
```

then you could write:

```
 string CancelUrl = doc.GetElementsByTagName("cbt:CancelUrl")[0].InnerText;
 string ChangeUrl = doc.GetElementsByTagName("cbt:ChangeUrl")[0].InnerText;
```

Comment: I didn't work much with good old `XmlDocument`. This is a shorter code than mine. Upvoted :)

Answer (score 2):

The way to select it, if using Linq to Xml is with defining an `XNamespace` object as follows:

```
XNamespace cbt = "http://xml.test.com/3.12.0.0/testTypes.xsd";

var result = XDocument.Load("data.xml").Root
         .Descendants(cbt + "CancelUrl")
         .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;

//result - https://store.test.com/
```

Comment: Yes, it helped. I upvoted your solution but accepted the other one since was shorter and clearer. Thanks :)

Comment: @eg16 - no problem :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `XmlDocument` class with the `XmlNamespaceManager` will support the XPath expressions you need to get the data.

```
//Load the document
XmlDocument order = new XmlDocument();
order.Load("filepath.xml");
```

Instantiate the namespace manager:

```
XmlNamespaceManager xmlns = new XmlNamespaceManager(order.NameTable);
xmlns.AddNamespace("cbt", "http://xml.test.com/3.12.0.0/testTypes.xsd");
```

Now you can use the namespace manager to select the information you need.
This XPath expression (`"//cbt:CancelUrl"`) selects any CancelUrl Node in the entire document, and could be made more specific with a more qualified path.

```
string xpath = "//cbt:CancelUrl"
XmlNode cancelUrl = Order.SelectSingleNode(xpath, xmlns);
string value = cancelUrl.InnerText;
```

You might want to specify the [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) more carefully, and make sure that the selected node isn't null after you selected it.