# Get value from simple XML document

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I have the following XML

```
<User 
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/GaryLeaderboardsAPI.Models">
    <Game_ID>3</Game_ID>
    <UserGUID>e00d3560-4133-4ba6-8bba-e6c8659468b4</UserGUID>
    <UserName>tony2</UserName>
    <User_ID>16</User_ID>
</User>
```

Using C# I am loading this into an XMLDocument, How do I retrieve the UserGUID value?

Comment: Looks like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39079867/4817341) might be able to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you.

```
string xml = "<User xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/GaryLeaderboardsAPI.Models\">" +
        "<Game_ID>3</Game_ID>" +
        "<UserGUID>e00d3560-4133-4ba6-8bba-e6c8659468b4</UserGUID>" +
        "<UserName>tony2</UserName>" +
        "<User_ID>16</User_ID>" +
        "</User>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

var id = doc.GetElementsByTagName("UserGUID")[0].InnerText;
```

Comment: @codemonkeytony if it solved your problem, please mark as an answer so other can refer it as well. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

Leveraging System.Xml.Linq you could do

```
string xml = "..."; // your inline XML
var doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

or

```
string xmlFile = "..."; // your XML filename
var doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
```

and then, to get the UserGUID

```
var userGuid = doc.Descendants().Where(x=>x.Name.LocalName == "UserGUID").First().Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the namespace.  I often use mipnw approach (probably stole idea from one of my postings).  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement user = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = user.GetDefaultNamespace();

            string UserGUID = (string)user.Element(ns + "UserGUID");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry to disappoint but I have not read your postings, Linq to XML is pretty standard stuff :)
By the way your solution makes it less obvious that only the first userGUID element is returned, I find the approach I've shared more transparent, and therefore less prone to bugs should the XML schema change and later allow multiple such elements.